# ASP.NET Core with Swashbuckle using inheritance and collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am working on an ASP.NET Core REST controller that uses Swashbuckle. My API response models use inheritance, and have associated `SwaggerSubType` and `SwaggerDiscriminator` attributes configured.

The API response will serialize to a derived class if I return a single object, but if I have a wrapper object that contains a collection of base class objects, then only the properties from the base class are returned in the response

```
public enum MyObjType { T1 }

[SwaggerDiscriminator("type")]
[SwaggerSubType(typeof(Sub1), DiscriminatorValue = nameof(MyObjType.T1))]
public abstract class Base
{
    MyObjType Type { get;set;}
}

public class Sub1
{
   public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseCollection
{
   public IEnumerable<Base> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So if I have an API that returns just a single object with type `Base` and it is a `Sub1` object type, then I get the `Name` property. But if I return an object of type `BaseCollection` and the `Items` property contains an item of `Sub1` type, the `Name` property is not returned in the response.

Swagger has been configured with:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                   c.EnableAnnotations(enableAnnotationsForInheritance: true, enableAnnotationsForPolymorphism: true);
                }
services.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                })
```

What do I need to do to get my REST API that returns an object of type `BaseCollection` to include all of the properties of the subclasses of `Base` class?

Comment: What's the question? Your post is very confusing to read though. Show examples of what you want, what you're getting, etc... This "question" is going to sit for a long time as-is with no responses (or wrong responses) due to the lack of information.

Comment: It looks like using `System.Text.Json` to serialize might be the problem. If use `services .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => ..)` it works properly.

Comment: So, not a question any more then?

Comment: It's still a question if someone can figure out how to get it to work with `System.Text.Json` and not `Newtonsoft`